# Change date in string format into date format

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that formats Excel spreadsheets.

The default date is saved as text.
Changing it via UI and recording that as a macro fails to recognize the dates within the autofilter.

It looks something like

```vb
Dim i As Integer
i = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("C1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
Dim k As Integer

For k = 3 To i
    Cells(k, 3) = Format(Cells(k, 3), "dd mmmm yyyy;@")
    ' Changing the format like dd.mm.yyyy;@ doesn't work at all 
Next k
```

[image]

[image]

This breaks on half the months like March, October, etc. When I double click the cell to edit it and hit enter the date gets saved correctly and is recognized by the autofilter.

Example of what it looks like inside the spreadsheet:
[image]

Comment: can you post some more data so I can test.

Comment: @LewisMorris sure, what exactly would you need?

Comment: Note that `Format()` will return text again and not numeric dates! Therefore this code cannot work. The only proper way is to write a parser to parse the text and create a numeric date with `DateSerial()`. Any auto conversion Excel does might go horribly wrong. Never let Excel guess or convert any texts to date! It may fail even if it looks to work in first place. • Please [edit] your question and include some more example data of your "dates". Where does the data come from? If it is a CSV or something make sure to import all dates as text so we can convert them properly.

Comment: to add - use like this DateSerial(year, month, day)... you might need to split your string date with left() right() or mid()

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like that Excel has converted **some** of the "dates" to numeric dates and some not. This is actually worst case. You need to prevent the auto conversion of the texts into dates completely in order to convert them properly and reliable.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried it as you suggested with DateSerial which seems to have fixed the problem. Is this a good way to go about it though? `Cells(k, 3) = DateSerial(Right(Cells(k, 3), 4), Mid(Cells(k, 3), 4, 2), Left(Cells(k, 3), 2))` Still new so I wouldn't want to go about it the wrong way.

Comment: @Slevin That won't work properly. First please [edit] and answer all the questions (without we cannot provide an answer that will work properly). The first thing needs to be where does this data come from and how can we stop Excel from converting **some** of the texts to dates. If we solved this then we can start thinking about converting them (not before).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I want to but I just don't understand what exactly I should edit into it. I don't think I can upload the spreadsheet here and as for dates, it's a larger one so essentially every day of the year is listed.

Comment: OK my first question: Where does the data come from? What is the source of the data? How do you get it into Excel? How do you import it? Because it looks like here is your first problem and this already went wrong.

Comment: I get sent those spreadsheets that someone else exports as .xlsx files from a program. He has no influence over how it's exported and sends those to me. I have manual workarounds to fix the dates by doing stuff like marking the column and doing a find and replace with "." the dots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243847/discussion-between-p-and-slevin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the following texts in A1:A13 that we want to convert to real numeric dates

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim RangeToConvert As Range
    Set RangeToConvert = Range("A1:A13")  ' define the range of texts DD.MM.YYYY you want to convert to real numeric dates
    
    ' read them into an array for faster processing
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Data = RangeToConvert.Value2
    
    ' convert all texts to dates in that array
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(iRow, 1) = ConvertTextDDMMYYYYtoDate(Data(iRow, 1))
    Next iRow
    
    ' write the real numerc dates back to the cells
    RangeToConvert.Value2 = Data
    
    ' format the date to whatever you like
    RangeToConvert.NumberFormat = "DD. MMM YYYY" 'however you want it to look like
End Sub


Public Function ConvertTextDDMMYYYYtoDate(ByVal DateString As String) As Date
    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(DateString, ".")  ' split date 13.01.2022 into 3 parts
    
    Dim RetVal As Date
    
    If UBound(Parts) = 2 Then ' check if there were 3 parts in the text if not it's the wrong format in the DateString 
        RetVal = DateSerial(Parts(2), Parts(1), Parts(0))  ' put the 3 parts together to a numeric date
        
        ' check if the numeric date is the same as the DateString we had as input
        If Format$(RetVal, "DD.MM.YYYY") <> DateString Then
            ' if that is not the case it means the string was no valid date and cannot be converted
            MsgBox """" & DateString & """ is not a valid date in the format TT.MM.JJJJ"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox """" & DateString & """ is not in the format TT.MM.JJJJ"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' return the value as real numeric date
    ConvertTextDDMMYYYYtoDate = RetVal
End Function
```

And the outcome will be

[image]

**Why did we do this `If Format$(RetVal, "DD.MM.YYYY") <> DateString Then`?**
Because if your strings are "wrong" dates like `35.01.2022` we need to detect hat. Because `DateSerial` would just convert it to the date `04.02.2022` because day `35` does not exist in january.

---

Edit according comment

If you have multiple columns you need a second loop that loops through the columns too.

```
Dim iCol As Long
For iCol = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(iRow, iCol ) = ConvertTextDDMMYYYYtoDate(Data(iRow, iCol ))
    Next iRow
Next iCol
```

Comment: How would I apply this solution if my goal is to use it for multiple columns? Setting the range like `Set RangeToConvert = Range("A1:B13")` does not change the B column

Comment: @Slevin See my edit.